# Can caching be leading to Gradle sync failure, after successfully building another app?

Tags: android, gradle, caching, synchronization

I'm really frustrated.  I'm new to Android development and Gradle.  Last week I was able to download Android Studio and created a simple app that contains a few buttons.  I had no trouble creating and running this.

This week I decided to create another, simpler app with no activities, to check whether my environment is set up properly.  After a couple of days, I cannot get the IDE to build the app, and the problems appear to be Gradle-related.

Here is my gradle-wrapper.properties file:

```
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

Here is my app-level build.gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

And here is the top-level gradle.build file:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I read up on additional repositories that are needed, and tried inserting this code into the top-level Gradle build file:

```
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

But this does not help.  When I try to build the project, I get errors saying that Gradle cannot find files (if I check the "offline" option) or when online, I see errors like this:
**Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'**

In Settings, I have "Auto-detect proxy settings" checked (I'm not behind a firewall), and I'm using Gradle from the gradle-wrapper.properties file.

Given that I'm able to rebuild the app I created last week, but cannot build this new app whatever I try, I'm wondering whether file caching might be causing this trouble.  I did try deleting the cached Gradle files from .gradle (I'm running on Windows 10) but that did not help.  Multiple times, I have tried invalidating the cache and restarting the IDE but this does not make a difference.

Comment: Have you tried Invalidate Cache s/Restart .? If not goto Files-> Invalidate Cache/Restart.
After it goes to Build ->Clean Project.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that multiple times, also tried deleting the .idea subdirectory and having the IDE re-index the files after restarting Android Studio.

Comment: I got it to work.  My company's IT department installed some modifications to our VPN last week that prevented Android Studio from connecting to Google.  I was able to browse to the download files on their site, so I thought that there should not have been a problem, plus I was able to build another app a couple of weeks ago while running the VPN.  But the VPN modification was installed after then, and before I tried to build another app.  Once I turned off the VPN, I was able to build and install my app.

Comment: Ahan that's great.